# When to use AuthorizeFilter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I've started looking into ASP.NET core, in particular Authorization. The model's changed quite a bit and I must say I'm finding it a little confusing compared to the last implementation.

I've seen various posts lamenting that it's now not possible to pass parameters to the Authorization attribute constructor and that instead we now have Policy/Requirement/Handler.

So what exactly is the user case for AuthorizeFilter? How does it differ from AuthorizeAttribute? When should I implement Requirement/Handler and when (or should I ever) implement an AuthorizeFilter (which looks like it might work closer to the old model)?

I couldn't find any resources online that detailed this particular aspect so any enlightenment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Documentation above the class of `AuthorizeFilter` says:

```
MVC recognizes the <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute" /> 
and adds an instance of this filter to the associated action or controller.
```

So when a controller is created an instance of the `AuthorizeFilter` is added to the controllers filters when a `AuthorizeAttribute` is present.

Basically they split the decoration: `AuthorizeAttribute` from the implementation: `AuthorizeFilter`.

So if you want clean code you can use `AuthorizeAttribute` to decorate your controller class.

if you want more understandable/logical code you can add te `AuthorizeFilter` to the filters in the Controller Constructor method.